# 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I am converting an adjacency matrix to graph object to data frame. I am trying the following code :

```
df.h <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(X_final,mode = "directed")
test2 <- as_long_data_frame(graph = df.h)
```

But, I am getting the error:

```
Error : Error in names(ver) <- paste0("from_", names(ver)) :    'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: I think you can resolve it by setting a name attribute, e.g. the vertex id: `V(g)$name <- V(g)` and then run `as_long_data_frame`.

Comment: @BenNutzer Your comment should be the answer. Maybe it's short but it does solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it solves the issue. Please include it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this function to work you need to specify a `name` attribute, e.g. the id of the graph:

```
set.seed(1)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10,.2)
V(g)$name <- V(g)
```

Then the function should run:

```
> head(as_long_data_frame(g), 5)
  from to ver[el[, 1], ] ver2[el[, 2], ]
1    2  3              2               3
2    3  4              3               4
3    4  7              4               7
4    5  7              5               7
5    5  8              5               8
```

However, I think it's a good catch of you: As of now (September 2019, `v1.2.4.1`) the overall function seems to be unfinished (see the cryptic colnames above). Once I add a second attribute, as proposed by the documentation `?as_long_data_frame`, the function works (fully) as intended:

```
V(g)$color <- colors()[1:10]
> head(as_long_data_frame(g), 5)
  from to from_name    from_color to_name      to_color
1    2  3         2     aliceblue       3  antiquewhite
2    3  4         3  antiquewhite       4 antiquewhite1
3    4  7         4 antiquewhite1       7 antiquewhite4
4    5  7         5 antiquewhite2       7 antiquewhite4
5    5  8         5 antiquewhite2       8    aquamarine
```